# How to parse odx-f file in cpp

Tags: c++, diagnostics

I want to parse an odx-f file using C++. But I can't find a single example of how to parse it. I am new to this site, can you please help me to solve this problem with example code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read  / learn about the file format specification and parse accordingly. All files are array of bytes. Format specification explains what those bytes mean. Or use third party libraries that do the job for you.

Comment: is that any odx file parser available in cpp?

Comment: can you please suggest a third party lib for me to do this

Comment: @Rajeev _"can you please suggest a third party lib ..."_ This is _off-topic_ here.

Comment: how to parse an odx file in cpp?

Comment: how to parse an xml file using cpp. is there any library support for doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

odx-f files containing the flash container data. To parse a .odx-f file in C++ you can use any XML parser (i.e. [rapidxml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/), [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/), [LibXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/index.html) with [C++ Wrapper](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/), ...). The following example will use rapidxml to print the `SHORT-NAME` of all `ECU-MEMS` and `ECU-MEM-CONNECTORS`. To access all other elements below `ECU-MEM` the same mechanism can be adapted (depends on which data your application requires from the .odx-f file).

```
#include <iostream>

#include "rapidxml/rapidxml.hpp"
#include "rapidxml/rapidxml_utils.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
  rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("myFile.odx-f");
  doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());
  rapidxml::xml_node<>* flashContainer = doc.first_node("ODX")->first_node("FLASH");
  if(flashContainer){
    std::cout << flashContainer->first_node("SHORT-NAME")->value() << std::endl; /* prints the shortname of the flash container */
    for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* ecuMem = flashContainer->first_node("ECU-MEMS")->first_node("ECU-MEM"); ecuMem; ecuMem = ecuMem->next_sibling("ECU-MEM")) {
      /* iterates over all ecu memory descriptors */
      std::cout << ecuMem->first_node("SHORT-NAME")->value() << std::endl; /* prints the shortname of the ecu memory descriptor */
    }
    for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* ecuMemCon = flashContainer->first_node("ECU-MEM-CONNECTORS")->first_node("ECU-MEM-CONNECTOR"); ecuMemCon; ecuMemCon = ecuMemCon->next_sibling("ECU-MEM-CONNECTOR")) {
      /* iterates over all ecu memory connectors */
      std::cout << ecuMemCon->first_node("SHORT-NAME")->value() << std::endl; /* prints the shortname of the ecu memory connector */
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There are also some libraries available to parse odx; usually they will be expensive as they're targeting commercial-use, but there is one library licensed under LGPLv2 called [ODX-Lib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/odx-lib/). However it is not updated since 2014 and in Java (JNI required to access from C++).